# Is there a standard way for UDP and TCP pinging?

Tags: tcp, udp, ping

Pinging is typically done via ICMP. I'd like to measure the real latency for UDP and TCP. I found that PsPing and PingPlotter have TCP and UDP modes, but I have no idea how those are working. Do I need some sort of echo server, or is there a standard, RFC, etc. for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [hping3](https://tools.kali.org/information-gathering/hping3):

> hping is a command-line oriented TCP/IP packet assembler/analyzer. The interface is inspired to the ping(8) unix command, but **hping isn’t only able to send ICMP echo requests. It supports TCP, UDP, ICMP and RAW-IP protocols**, has a traceroute mode, the ability to send files between a covered channel, and many other features.